# Building a top-down parking camera

Tags: streaming-video, cars, video-input

I'm looking to build something like [this](https://www.whichcar.com.au/car-advice/360-degree-parking-monitors-explained) using a Pi.

As I understand it, it needs to handle 4 simultaneous video streams + perspective transformations and output it to a display. I'm not very familiar with the Pi ecosystem so I don't even know if the hardware can handle something like that.

What libraries/resources should I be looking at? Ideas or other guidance of where to start are very much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Is this relevant to the Pi?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I've seen examples of Pi-based head units with reversing cameras but not a top-down version.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is too broad and opinion based. Such questions are flagged and may be closed. This site isn't made for brainstorming and discuss general issues. It is made to do one specific question that can be answered detailed. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is something which the latest Pi 4 model B should be able to handle, although your resolution and framerate may be low.

The [web page for the motion](https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html) camera controller project says:

> USB cameras take a lot of bandwidth. A USB camera connected to a USB2
>   port or hub consumes virtually all the bandwidth that the port can
>   handle. Even with a small framesize and low framerate you should not
>   expect to have more than one camera per USB controller.

All Raspberry Pi devices before the Pi 4 [only contain USB2 hubs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/usb/README.md), so will not work with four cameras.

The Pi 4 has two USB3 ports connected via fast PCIe, so it would be possible, with the addition of a USB3 hub, to connect four cameras to a Pi 4 for this application.

The perspective transformation is going to be fairly CPU-heavy. The quad-core BCM2711 in the Pi 4 model B will likely handle it at low resolution and low framerate, but you're going to have to try it to find out if it will be acceptable.